# Merge multiple files into a single row file with a delimeter

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, cut

**UPDATED QS:**
I have been working on a bash script that will merge multiple text files with numerical values into one a single row text file using delimiter for each file values while merging

Example:

```
File1.txt has the followling contents:
168321099
File2.txt has:
151304
151555
File3.txt has:
16980925
File4.txt has:
154292
149092

Now i want a output.txt file like below:
, 168321099 151304 151555 16980925 , 154292 149092
```

Basically each file delimited by **space** and in a **single row.** with **comma as first and 6 field of the outputrow**

tried:

```
cat * > out.txt but its not coming as expected
```

Comment: Execute a Vim macro. The sequence would be (without apostrophes): "ggVGJZZ" which means: gg - go to beginning of the file, V- select entire lines, G - go to end of file, J - concatenate lines, ZZ - save and quit. Or - easier - execute search replace with sed : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I replace a newline (\n) using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed)

Answer (score 1):

I am not very sure If I understood your question correctly, but I interpreted it as following :

- The set of files `file1,...,filen` contain a set of words which you want to have printed in one single line.
- Each word is space separated
- In addition to the string of words, you want the first character to be a `,` and between word 4 and 5 you want to have a `,`.

**The `cat`+`tr`+`awk` solution:**

```
$ cat <file1> ... <filen> | tr '\n' ' ' | awk '{$1=", "$1; $4=$4" ,"; print}'
```

**The `awk` solution:**

```
$ awk 'NR==1||NR==4{printf s",";s=" "}{printf " "$1}' <file1> ... <filen>
```

Answer (score 0):

If `tr` is available on your system you can do the following `cat * | tr "\n" " " > out.txt`

`tr "\n" " "` translates all line breaks to spaces

Answer (score 0):

If the number of lines per file is constant, then the easiest way is `tr` as @Littlefinix suggested, with a couple of anonymous files to supply the commas, and an echo at the end to add an explicit newline to the output line:

```
cat <(echo ",") File1.txt File2.txt File3.txt <(echo ",") File4.txt | tr "\n" " " > out.txt; echo >> out.txt
```

out.txt is exactly what you specified:

```
, 168321099 151304 151555 16980925 , 154292 149092
```

If the number of lines per input file might vary (e.g., File2.txt has 3 or 4 lines, etc.), then placing the commas always in the 1st and 6th field will be more involved, and you'd probably need a script and not a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

Following single `awk` could help you on same.

```
awk 'FNR==1{count++;} {printf("%s%s",count==1||(count==(ARGC-1)&&FNR==1)?", ":" ",$0)} END{print ""}' *.txt
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '
FNR==1        {   count++                                                         }
              {   printf("%s%s",count==1||(count==(ARGC-1)&&FNR==1)?", ":" ",$0)  }
END           {   print ""                                                        }
' *.txt
```